# Using parfor in Matlab with struct varying across iteration

Tags: matlab

I would like to re-write the following loop using `parfor` in place of `for` in Matlab. I would like your help to understand which is the best way to proceed.

The crucial thing is that the line `result=gurobi(model)` wants a structure as input and splits a structure. Two fields of the structure `model` vary across iterations. I imagine I should somehow preallocate a structure `model` composed of `100` sub-structures but I cannot go more far than that and I would appreciated your help.

Notice: all the variables used in this loop are created somewhere else. I did not included that part of the code.

```
L=zeros(100,1)
for b=1:100
    model.A=[Aineq; Aeq];
    model.rhs=[bineq;beq]; 
    model.sense=[repmat('<', size(Aineq,1),1); repmat('=', size(Aeq,1),1)];
    model.Q=Qsub{b}; %VARYING WITH b
    model.obj=csub{b}; %VARYING WITH b
    model.vtype=type; 
    model.lb=total_lb;
    model.ub=total_ub;
    result=gurobi(model); 
    L(b)=(result.objval+alphasub{b})*B;
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend setting all of the non-varying fields outside of the loop. Inside of the loop you can create a "local_model" copy of the structure and insert any of the varying fields. This will allow you to use a parfor loop.

Try something similar to the following:

```
model.A=[Aineq; Aeq];
model.rhs=[bineq;beq]; 
model.sense=[repmat('<', size(Aineq,1),1); repmat('=', size(Aeq,1),1)];
model.vtype=type; 
model.lb=total_lb;
model.ub=total_ub;

L=zeros(100,1)
parfor b=1:100
    local_model = model;
    local_model.Q=Qsub{b}; %VARYING WITH b
    local_model.obj=csub{b}; %VARYING WITH b

    result=gurobi(local_model); 
    L(b)=(result.objval+alphasub{b})*B;
end
```